# multi column drop down menus

Tags: 7, routes

Is there a menu module through which we can create multi column drop down menus. I have tried TB Mega Menu which gives the desired result but it has some issues. The worst part is that it converts into mobile menu on resizing the window or smaller screens even if we are not designing the responsive website and there is no option to disable the mobile menu.

Comment: TB Megamenu can be tamed, it's just a bit of a pain. You need to manually adjust the breakpoints in css/base.css, css/bootstrap.css, css/default.css and css/styles/black.css (the last one may change depending on your theme). I found it easier just to patch the module than to work out all the right overrides

Comment: Where is the difficulty? In producing the HTML, or the CSS ?